# Putting delay in read and write from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

Hi I'm writing an application to work with a device by using serial port. I've written the code and it works fine when I put breaking points but when I debug it with out breaking points the expected data is part by part. For example when I put break points and read from port the correct data is "ali" but when I remove breaking points the data will be "a" ,"li" .
here's my snippet code for writing and reading from port :

```
 fname1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("write1"  + dataRow[0].ToString());
 comport.Write(fname1,0,fname1.Length);
 lname1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("write4" + dataRow[1].ToString());
 comport.Write(lname1, 0, lname1.Length); 

c3 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("read" +0x1);
comport.Write(c3,0,c3.Length);
comport.Read(fname1, 0, fname1.Length);
string s = Encoding.Default.GetString(fname1);
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

I assume cause I have encoding there is some time wasting and this explains the effect of breaking point which I described.

My solution is to put delay in two consecutive read or write . Am I correct ? If yes how can I implement that? Is there a better way?

Comment: please include the code where you do the "read".

Comment: it's on button click and second part of above code does the read. I should send "read" and a block number as byte to my device to operate the read command

Comment: no, I mean the part of your code where you call the `SerialPort.Read` method. Are you doing it in a `DataReceived` event handler?

Comment: Oh you're right sorry it's right after `comport.Write(c3,0,c3.Length);`. The code is `comport.Read(fname1, 0, fname1.Length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you call `comport.Read`, that reads whatever data is available to be read. It is quite possible that the whole message has not arrived at the serial port yet.

If you're expecting a certain number of bytes, then you could use a loop like:

```
var bytesReceived= 0;
while(bytesReceived < fname1.Length)
{
    bytesReceived += 
        comport.Read(fname1, bytesReceived, fname1.Length - bytesReceived);
}
```

It is also possible to read a single line using `SerialPort.ReadLine`, or read upto a certain string using `SerialPort.ReadTo`.

For more info on those methods, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort_methods.aspx).